# Cosmos DB SDK Query speeds are really slow compared to query statistics in Azure Portal

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I created a POC to test Cosmos Db. For that purpose i created a container. Each Partition Key has 120 item. I provided 500 "partitions" so it means, that i have 60k documents loaded into container.

My document looks like this:

```json
{
    "id": // id
    "SteamId": // partition key as string
    "Profile": {
        // object
    }
}
```

One document is 5kb of size.

For that scenario i prepared indexing policy tailored for my needs:

```json
{
    "indexingMode": "consistent",
    "automatic": true,
    "includedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/SteamId/?"
        }
    ],
    "excludedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/*"
        },
        {
            "path": "/\"_etag\"/?"
        }
    ]
}
```

When i execute query in portal:

```sql
SELECT c.Profile FROM c where c.SteamId = "76561198053126645"
```

Thats my stats:
[image]
[image]

So it looks really fast and efficient. I try to download full partition which is 500kb of data.

And now i prepared really simple c# code:

```cs
        public async Task<IActionResult> test(string steamid)
        {
            CosmosClient client = new(
                accountEndpoint: "endpoint",
                tokenCredential: new DefaultAzureCredential()
            );
            
            Database database = client.GetDatabase("items");
            Container container = database.GetContainer("items3");

            var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            var queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition($"SELECT c.Profile FROM c where c.SteamId = {steamid}");
            var iterator = container.GetItemQueryIterator<aaa>(queryDefinition,
                requestOptions: new QueryRequestOptions()
                {
                    PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(steamid),
                });

            var results = new List<aaa>();

            stopwatch.Start();

            while (iterator.HasMoreResults)
            {
                var result = await iterator.ReadNextAsync();
                results.AddRange(result.Resource);
            }
            stopwatch.Stop();
            

            return Ok(new { items = results, time = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds });
        }
```

And that request through SDK take **10 seconds** to load the same query that in portal took **1 ms**. What am i doing wrong in SDK that it take so much time in local environment? I am living in the same region where Cosmos Db resource is provisioned. I am using `SDK version 3.36` for `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos`

Metrics from Cosmos DB SQL Studio:
[image]

Comment: Connect and authenticate outside of your testing code. The Cosmos connection can and should be shared so you're not opening and closing it every time you do a request. Also warm up the runtime when you test so you're not including any JIT overheads in your test (write the test with the BenchmarkDotNet package, it will do this for you)

Comment: 1ms is incredibly low latency. This indicates the query is being executed in a VM in Azure in the same data center. You're definitely going to have more latency, but it shouldn't be 10 seconds though. Have you tried doing the same query from something like Azure Cosmos DB SQL Studio?

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson metrics from Cosmos DB extension attached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analyzing latency on a post here is rather impossible as it is not a programming problem. Latency should be analyzed throughout a longer period of time than 1 operation.

Particularly because connections always have a warm-up phase, and according to https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/sdk-connection-modes#direct-mode, **the first ever operation you do initializes and bootstraps the client with all the information needed to route requests**, it will **always have higher latency**. This is known generally as **cold start**.

Services measure latency on P99 basis.

In general, when looking at latency troubleshooting, the main article is: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/troubleshoot-dotnet-sdk-slow-request?tabs=cpu-new

Comment: Thank you, I will dig into it, maybe i will do kind of "load test" to warm up cosmos client and i will share results in the comment here.

Comment: When i registered cosmos client as singleton it works like a charm, thank you!